# Cross compiling gtkmm on Linux for Windows gives error "unrecognized option ‘-pthread’"

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling, gtkmm, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile simple "Hello World!" gtkmm source code provided in gtkmm [tutorial](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.0/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en) with mingw on Linux in order to make a Windows executable file.

I can execute complied source code by the following command line: `` g++ main.cpp -o bin `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` `` on linux and everything **works fine** but when I try to use `` i686-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -o bin `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` ``, it fails showing this error:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized option ‘-pthread’
```

Is there anything that I miss and must be installed before compiling ?

And also, is there a neat tutorial for cross-compiling (especially about gtk+ or gtkmm)? I have searched a lot but there was nothing useful.

Comment: Have you modified the `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR` and `PKG_CONFIG_DIR` environment variables so that pkg-config returns options for the cross compilation rather than the native compilation ?

Comment: No, could you give me a little bit more explanation or a link to helpful document ?

Comment: You should already have found this one: http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/pkgconfig/cross-compiling.html